# MySQL .Net Connector Connection is Opened but Closed

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have a very strange problem with the newest MySQL .Net Connector.

Following code:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE tst SET col1 = 'Test' WHERE id = 5", conn);

if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    conn.Open();
}

Console.WriteLine(conn.State.ToString());
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(conn.State.ToString());
}
```

If I run my programm I will get following output / error:

```
Open
The connection must be valid and open
Open
```

How is this possible. Do you have any idea?

Comment: try declaring the cmd just before executing it. It might be because the conn is used before it's opened. (not sure)

Comment: Does the same issue happen if you call `conn.Open` before creating the command?

Comment: It will be better if you include a stacktrace as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) for `MySql` and at [DevArt](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand~_ctor(String,MySqlConnection,MySqlTransaction).html), all the `MySqlCommand`'s are initialized with a open connection. I suggest to open the connection first and initialize the `MySqlCommand` afterward.

```
if (!conn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
    conn.Open();

Console.WriteLine(conn.State.ToString());

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE tst SET col1 = 'Test' WHERE id = 5", conn);

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(conn.State.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all, it's correct to open the connection first.
The interesting thing is, that I used this logic at many locations in my code and there it worked perfectly.